# limitar paginador con php y bootstrap

Tags: php, bootstrap

Buenos dias espero me puedan ayudar con un inconveniente que tengo, resulta que tengo una tabla con mas de 10000 registros, tengo el paginador que funciona correctamente pero en el momento de motrarlo saca todas las paginas que son como 600 en una sola fila, como hago para que el paginador me muestre por ejemplo

anterior 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... siguiente

y no todas la paginas

aqui esta el codigo por si alguien me puede ayudar de antemano gracias

```
<?php
include_once 'include_conexion.php';

if(!$_GET){
    header('Location:equipo_tipoequipo.php?pagina=1');
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tipo_equipo WHERE nom_equipo != 'Nulo'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

$registros = $resultado->num_rows;
$paginacion = 15;
$paginas = $registros/$paginacion;
$paginas =  ceil($paginas);

if($_GET['pagina']>$paginas || $_GET['pagina']<0){
    header('Location:equipo_tipoequipo.php?pagina=1');
}

include 'include_cabecera.php';
?>
<?php include 'permisos/permisos.php';?>
<?php if($per_adm > '0'):?> 

<?php 
$iniciar = ($_GET['pagina']-1)*$paginacion;

$sql_equipos = "SELECT * FROM tipo_equipo WHERE nom_equipo != 'Nulo' LIMIT $iniciar, $paginacion";
$resultado_equipos = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_equipos) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

?>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead class="thead-primary">
    <tr style="white-space:nowrap;">
        <th scope="col" class="something">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
        <th scope="col" class="something">Editar</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php while($fila= mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_equipos)) {?>
<tbody class="buscar">
    <tr style="white-space:nowrap;">
        <th scope="row" class="something"><?php echo utf8_encode($fila['tip_equ_id']); ?></th>
        <td><?php echo utf8_encode($fila['nom_equipo']); ?></td>
        <td class="something">
            <a href="equipo_tipoequipoeditar.php?id=<?php echo $fila['tip_equ_id'];?>" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['pagina']<=1 ? 'disabled':'' ?>">
        <a class="page-link" href="equipo_tipoequipo.php?pagina=<?php echo $_GET['pagina']-1 ?>">Anterior</a>
    </li>

    <?php for($i=0;$i<$paginas;$i++): ?>
    <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['pagina']==$i+1 ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a class="page-link" 
        href="equipo_tipoequipo.php?pagina=<?php echo $i+1 ?>">
        <?php echo $i+1 ?>
    </a></li>
    <?php endfor ?>
    <li class="page-item
    <?php echo $_GET['pagina']>=$paginas ? 'disabled':'' ?>">
    <a class="page-link" 
    href="equipo_tipoequipo.php?pagina=<?php echo $_GET['pagina']+1 ?>">Siguiente</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>

<?php include 'include_footer.php';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba esto a ver si te funciona, tienes que darle unos ajustes para que el paginator se adapte a lo que requieres. yo lo utilizo de la siguiente forma junto a mi consulta sql

```html
include 'pagination.php'; // incluir archivo de paginación
  // variables de paginación
  $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
  $per_page = 10; // ¿Cuántos items quieres mostrar?
  $adjacents  = 4; // Brecha entre páginas después del número de adyacentes.
  $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
  // Cuenta el número total de filas en la tabla */
  // $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable AS asis INNER JOIN $aTable AS per ON asis.id_personal = per.cedula $sWhere $FechaWhere $order");
  $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable $FechaWhere");
  $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
  $numrows = $row['numrows'];

  $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
    
    aqui colocas tu consulta sql 
    
    los registros
    
    y luego
    
    <?php
      echo paginate($reload, $page, $total_pages, $adjacents);
     ?>
```